# How do you find the inverse of a function?

Tags: python, numpy, math, inverse

There are also other variables, such as c1, n1, k1 and so on but they are only being used as placeholders for a random number from 1 to 10. Specifically, I am trying to find the maximum y-value of a function, calculate %90 of that value, and then plug that back in to the inverse of the function in order to find the x-value at 90% of maximum y-value. I am able to calculate the rest of these except I have to manually find the inverse of a function which is going to be an issue when I eventually have to find this x-value at 90% of input for any function. Also I am going to be mainly using sigmoidal functions.

This is one of the functions that I want to find the inverse for:

```html
def c(x):
    return ((c1*x**(n2*n1))*(c2**n1))/((k2*(k2+(x**n2))**n1)+((c2**n1)*(x**(n2*n1))))
```

Key issue: I need to use python to find the inverse of a function.

Comment: Using maths? Write out the function as maths statement, and either rewrite it yourself (this looks like a pretty simply function with a few powers), or ask wolframalpha to do it for you. After first plotting it and seeing if it _can_ be inverted, because that's a dangerous assumption to make without verifying =) But on a programming note: why are all those "not x" variables not in the function signature? Even if you give them default values based on globals, make them function arguments at the very least.

Comment: I know that I can use basic math to rewrite the function but I want to completely automate it in just python. Additionally, what do you mean by a default value based on globals and making them function arguments?

Comment: Python lets you specify defaults using assignment in the function signature. E.g. `def calculateWhatever(x, c1=default_values.c1, c2=..., n1=..., ....)` because if your function relies on global values, your function can be broken _instantly_ by something updating those globals. Better to have function args and call it with the right values. As for inverting a function in Python rather than by just spending the time up front and hardcoding it... why? Your function is fully described, just work out the maths and implement the inverse function?

Comment: There's no general way to compute the inverse of an arbitrary calculation.

Comment: And unless you're using something like sympi, you can't even get the calculation as a formula out of a function. When you call a function, you just get the result, without knowing how it was calculated -- it's a "black box".

Comment: If you want to extract the original expression from that code you're going to have to do some bytecode manipulation in addition to implementing an equation solver, the first of which is merely very difficult without knowledge of bytecode, and the second of which is the subject of many, many papers, and is unsolvable in the general case.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am trying to use this function for any type of sigmoidal function and since there are many, I would like to find a way to automate this rather than me manually finding it out. However, looking at the other responses as well as yours I think it would be best to hardcode it after all. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Barmar Ahh okay. I was kind of confused though because I know that there are some libraries like pynverse and scipy.optimize however their documentation is confusing to me.

Comment: @Mous Oh wow that sounds really complicated. I think im better off hardcoding it after all.

Comment: @Mous I mean, I think you could use `sympy` you wouldn't have to write it yourself.

Comment: These comments are all completely bizarre. OP doesn't want a general equation solver, he/she is working on a specific problem, as shown. The problem is not easy but it is tractable. All these vague dismissals are unconstructive.

Answer (score 2):

You can use root-finding methods to numerically find the inverse of a function.

However, you should carefully check the shape of the function.

- There can be multiple x values that result in a same f(x) value.
- Numerical methods can fail to find a root if the shape of the function is complicated.

For example, your function generates similar values in many cases:

```
def f(x, c1, c2, n1, n2, k2):
    return ((c1*x**(n2*n1))*(c2**n1))/((k2*(k2+(x**n2))**n1)+((c2**n1)*(x**(n2*n1))))

f(10000.0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
> 1.8620689655172415

f(1000.0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
> 1.8620689655172382

f(10.0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
> 1.8620381428016617

f(8.0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
> 1.861974887879328
```

You will not get an exact inverse value for this function:

```
def f_inv_opt(x, y, c1, c2, n1, n2, k2):
    return abs(f(x, c1, c2, n1, n2, k2) - y)

scipy.optimize.minimize(f_inv_opt, x0 = 2.0, args = (f(1000.0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
> 10.99236547

scipy.optimize.minimize(f_inv_opt, x0 = 100.0, args = (f(1000.0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
> 100.0

scipy.optimize.minimize(f_inv_opt, x0 = 1000.0, args = (f(1000.0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
> 1000.0
```

Note. `SymPy` cannot analytically solve your complicated equation.

Moreover, I am not sure about the existence of the analytical inverse.

```
import sympy

x = sympy.symbols('x')
y = sympy.symbols('y')
c1 = sympy.symbols('C_1')
c2 = sympy.symbols('C_2')
n1 = sympy.symbols('n_1')
n2 = sympy.symbols('n_2')
k2 = sympy.symbols('k_2')

expr = ((c1*x**(n2*n1))*(c2**n1))/((k2*(k2+(x**n2))**n1)+((c2**n1)*(x**(n2*n1))))

eqn = sympy.Eq(y, expr)
inv = sympy.solve(eqn, x)
> NotImplementedError
```

Comment: I agree that numerical root finding is a useful approach here. @alpha_lupi: bear in mind that how well numerical approaches work will depend strongly on the values of the free parameters c1, c2, etc. Plug in some typical values for the parameters and see what the function looks like. If it is well-behaved, forge ahead. Otherwise, you might need to look for another approach.

Comment: About the "analytical" inverse (more accurate to say symbolic, I think), it might not be very useful, even if there is one; it's often easier to work with numerical approximations instead of constructing an inverse and evaluating it.